# An action triggered automatically after a programmatic segue

Tags: ios, swift, timer, segue

I use this simple code to segue:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSeqTwo", sender: self)
```

After this segue, I need a timer in the controller to launch automatically. The problem is that normally the timer is supposed to be launched by pressing a play button, and then paused and relaunched at will. The user can also swipe to this controller, in which case the timer should not be triggered. Can I send some kind of a signal with this particular segue to programmatically "push" the button and launch the timer?

Comment: Use prepare(for segue:) in the parent view controller and set a flag on the destination view controller indicating what the timer/button state should be. in the destination view controller examine the value of the flag in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Essence... which event work best, **viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear(). I like your answer but tend to use viewWillAppear() in my apps. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a variable that is read in the viewDidLoad() function of the second viewController, and determine if the play button should activate.

Add a function to the bottom of your first viewController like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showSeqTwo" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! NameOfSecondViewControllerClass
        destination.segueFlag = 1
    }
}
```

Inside the second viewController, add the following variable into the class:

```
var segueFlag = 0
```

Inside the viewDidLoad() of the second viewController, add the following code

```
if segueFlag == 1 {
    // Add function to start play button here
}
```